# Metamask not loading transaction fee on Ropsten

Tags: solidity, metamask, ropsten

I'm trying to send test Ether to a contract on Ropsten, but Metamask won't load the gas options on the send transaction screen. It displays a "Loading" text and never renders the Fastest/Fast/Slow options. It also doesn't let me manually enter the Gas price in the Advanced Options menu.

Comment: What is the address of the contract you are trying to send to?